# bootstrap nav tabs-custom style using breadcrumbs

Tags: css, breadcrumbs

I have added custom style for bootstrap nav-tabs using breadcrumbs.

```
<div> 
   <div class="breadcrumb">
       <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="active"><a href="#submitted" data-toggle="tab">Submitted</a></li>
          <li><a href="#pendingApproval" data-toggle="tab">Pending Approval</a></li>
          <li><a href="#workInProgress" data-toggle="tab">Work In Progress</a></li>
          <li><a href="#complete" data-toggle="tab">Complete</a></li>
       </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="tab-content" style="margin:5%;">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="submitted">
         Submitted data will be displayed here....
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="pendingApproval">
        Pending Approvals will be displayed here....
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="workInProgress">
         In Progress data will be displayed here....
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="complete">
         Completed data will be displayed here....
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

But last tab style is looking different.I want all tabs in same design(like arrow).How can I get it?

Working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/70Luf7hu/28/

Comment: I don't know about clip-path, but you might want to have a look at this: https://css-tricks.com/triangle-breadcrumbs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add clip-path to the outer breadcrumb div also and adjust the padding-right for the border width.

https://jsfiddle.net/70Luf7hu/42/

```
.breadcrumb {
    background: #ddd;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 15px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 15px) 100%, 0 100%, 15px 50%);
}
```

Comment: Its working fine but left border for first menu is getting hided.

Comment: can I customize that left side of first menu as straight line?